# Hibernate - How to do with foreign key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, foreign-keys

I have some difficulties with foreign key and hibernate.

I'm using Spring 4 and Hibernate 5. I have two mysql table, Utilisateur and Adresse.

For me, one user have one address and one address have one user. SO, this is a One-to-one relation (correct me if I make a mistake :) ). So, I did this:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id")
public Utilisateur getIdUtilisateur() {
    return idUtilisateur;
}
```

However, when I launch my main, I have these exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2921)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3421)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:560)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1295)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3135)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2352)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
    at com.ecollection.dao.AdresseDaoImpl.creerAdresse(AdresseDaoImpl.java:30)
    at com.ecollection.service.AdresseServiceImpl.creerAdresse(AdresseServiceImpl.java:26)
    at TestMain.main(TestMain.java:39)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'idUtilisateur' doesn't have a default value
```

This is my main :

```
    UtilisateurServiceImpl utilisateurService = new UtilisateurServiceImpl();

    Utilisateur utilisateur = new Utilisateur("Valjeant", "Jean");

    utilisateurService.creerUtilisateur(utilisateur);

    AdresseServiceImpl adresseService = new AdresseServiceImpl();

    Adresse nouvelleAdresse = new Adresse("avenue du champagne", "51100", "reims", "france", utilisateur);

    adresseService.creerAdresse(nouvelleAdresse);
```

Do you have an idea?

Comment: According to the error trace, It looks like you missed the id generation for pk of Utilisateur class or it didn't work, also, would you mind if you use cascade insert for this relationship? See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

I assume it's bidirectional relationship, try:
in Adresse class:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "adresse", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public get getUtilisateur() {
        return this.idUtilisateur;
}
```

in Utilisateur class:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
public Adresse getGetAdresse() {
    return this.adresse;
}
```

See [this link](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example-annotation/)

Comment: Thanks. In my database, Utilisateur (user in english) doesn't know the Address' id. Perhaps it's not a One-to-One relation ?

Comment: So It is an unidirectional one to one relation since one Utilisateur class has no knowledge about Adresse class. Can I see your class Utilisateur? at least a part with PK?

Comment: Yes, see my answer :)

Comment: Did you try to add 
`fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "adresse", cascade = CascadeType.ALL` to your @OneToOne annotaion above geIdtUtilisateur()? Because it looks like that the object utilisateur does not have id in it when you create new Address, so you can solve it using Cascade

Comment: I just add it and I have this exception :

Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.ecollection.model.Adresse.idUtilisateur, referenced property unknown: com.ecollection.model.Utilisateur.adresse

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, since it's an unidirectional you can get rid of mappedBy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is my two classes (without imports) :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="UTILISATEUR")
public class Utilisateur {

    public Long id;

    public String nom;
    public String prenom;

    public Utilisateur() {
        super();
    }

    public Utilisateur(String nom, String prenom) {
        super();
        this.nom = nom;
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Utilisateur [id=" + id + ", nom=" + nom + ", prenom=" + prenom  + "]";
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment",strategy="increment")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }


}
```

Adresse :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ADRESSE")
public class Adresse {

    private Long id;

    private String rue;
    private String codePostal;
    private String ville;
    private String pays;

    private Utilisateur idUtilisateur;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ""
                + "Adresse [rue=" 
                + rue 
                + ", codePostal=" 
                + codePostal 
                + ", ville=" 
                + ville 
                + ", pays=" 
                + pays 
                + "]";
    }

    public Adresse() {
    }

    public Adresse(String rue, String codePostal, String ville, String pays) {
        super();
        this.rue = rue;
        this.codePostal = codePostal;
        this.ville = ville;
        this.pays = pays;
    }

    public Adresse(String rue, String codePostal, String ville, String pays, Utilisateur idUtilisateur) {
        super();
        this.rue = rue;
        this.codePostal = codePostal;
        this.ville = ville;
        this.pays = pays;
        this.idUtilisateur = idUtilisateur;
    }

    /*
     * GETTERS/SETTERS
     */

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment",strategy="increment")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the rue
     */
    public String getRue() {
        return rue;
    }

    /**
     * @param rue the rue to set
     */
    public void setRue(String rue) {
        this.rue = rue;
    }

    /**
     * @return the codePostal
     */
    public String getCodePostal() {
        return codePostal;
    }

    /**
     * @param codePostal the codePostal to set
     */
    public void setCodePostal(String codePostal) {
        this.codePostal = codePostal;
    }

    /**
     * @return the ville
     */
    public String getVille() {
        return ville;
    }

    /**
     * @param ville the ville to set
     */
    public void setVille(String ville) {
        this.ville = ville;
    }

    /**
     * @return the pays
     */
    public String getPays() {
        return pays;
    }

    /**
     * @param pays the pays to set
     */
    public void setPays(String pays) {
        this.pays = pays;
    }

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    public Utilisateur getIdUtilisateur() {
        return idUtilisateur;
    }

    public void setIdUtilisateur(Utilisateur idUtilisateur) {
        this.idUtilisateur = idUtilisateur;
    }

}
```

In SQL request :

Select * from utilisateur u, adresse a WHERE u.id = a.idUtilisateur

=D